# How do I map a recursive data structure in mongo to java?

Tags: quarkus-panache

I want to know how can I map this json stored in mongo to java classes using quarkus panache mongo.
Are there any annotations available like @Inheritance and all in mongo panache.

```
"ruleCriteria": {
    "combinator": "and",
    "rules": [
      {
        "attribute": "name",
        "operator": "equalsIgnoreCase",
        "value": "dasfsd"
      },
      {
        "combinator": "and",
        "rules": [
          {
            "attribute": "timeOfCreation",
            "operator": "lessThan",
            "value": {
              "date": "2023-08-01",
              "time": "03:03:02"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "combinator": "or",
        "rules": [
          {
            "attribute": "owners",
            "operator": "equals",
            "value": "werwqerqr"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

I am expected reference to features and documentation specific to this problem for mongo panache.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer so basically your problem start when you want to make the represent the array because that's recursive. And the Java Mapping from json canbe resolved with @JsonSubTypes annotation of jackson. If you are using jackson. And on mongo side you can use @bsondiscriminator annotation.